# ADT Bundle's Menus Does Not Open on 13.10

Tags: android, eclipse, menu, menu-bar

I download Android Bundle 64bit to my 64bit Ubuntu 13.10. Installation was correct. Bundle opens properly but when I try to use top menus of Eclipse they don't open. How I can solve this problem?

[image]